# How to measure the Intensity of light?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics

I'm working on a project and I need to measure the Intensity of light( that is appeared on a screen ) in some different places of it to compare them ( in order to compare the amount of reflection )
I want you to tell me a way or an Instrument or something else that I can measure the Intensity of different points of a light on the screen to compare them

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say "screen" do you mean a passive projection surface or a active display?

Comment: A passive. Imagine we have aimed a flashlight on the screen and want to measure the intensity of light on that passive screen

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to measure foot-candles, which are units of light intensity received by a passive surface.  This is an appropriate measure if the surface reflects light from another source.  It's **not** the right measure for the output of a computer screen.

Also, you seem to want to measure at specific places on the screen.  Here are some foot candle meters that have a detachable sensor so you can measure without throwing a shadow: http://www.grainger.com/category/ecatalog/N-1z0dwax.  These are lower price models: http://www.dasdistribution.com/products/lm-economical_models.htm.

The foot candle is not an SI unit.  It equals about 1 lumen per square foot.  It's been replaced by the candela, which is 1 lumen per square meter.  But as the candela measures light filling a 3-dimensional angular span, I think you would want to use the Lux, which measures light received by a surface.

A lumen is a measure of luminous flux, which includes only light that is visible to the human eye.  If you want to measure the radiant power of a light source, you would measure radiant flux, which includes all wavelengths whether visible to the human eye or not.

Here is a better explanation and a reference for various units in which visible light can be measured, and the appropriate situations for each type of measurement: http://www.compuphase.com/electronics/candela_lumen.htm.